# GoInstant REST API 'Remove a Key' doesn't propagate event

Tags: php, goinstant

I'm using PHP cURL. My clients are using GoAngular.

REST API 'Remove a Key' (DELETE) doesn't seem to be triggering an event as far as the client apps are concerned. The DELETE is successful in that I do receive a *lastValue* response. When I inspect the room, the key is gone as expected. If I do a browser reload, it updates correctly, and that does propagate updates to the other clients.

Am I missing something or is there a way to just fire an **update** event in the room to hit the client listeners?

Comment: Hey Adam, we're having someone look into the issue your experiencing!  As an aside I'm the primary developer on GoAngular and I'm preparing to launch a new version, if you might be willing to take it for test drive, let me know, I'd love your feedback and honestly, it includes some significant improvements! :)

Comment: I've confirmed that deleting a key via the REST API triggers a remove event for the client. HTML: http://pastebin.com/d1xHtr5x, CURL command: http://pastebin.com/utDPNBXf

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of you code?

Comment: Sorry, Pastebin was acting up. Took a while to upload/save the edit.

Comment: I was just thinking it's more likely what the client is listening to. I followed the ToDo demo and it's the array in the key, that I'm deleting.

Comment: Thanks...the Pastbin worked, the alert displayed when I removed the key. But the input text was still displayed. I thought some listener would update the contents? I guess I'm still not clear on the workings. I'll study tonight and see if i can grok. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a key via the REST API will trigger a remove event for the clients. See the working example client here: http://pastebin.com/d1xHtr5x

If you want to clear the input box after the remove event you should do that within the remove event callback:

```
name.on('remove', function() {
    el.val('');
});
```